# Error in code publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I publish the code then it is not copying in web folder that exists in wwwroot .
Empty folder is there but while publishing it is saying that Site was published successfully.

After that it open blank browser with message (To Parent Directory)

It is giving no error.

```
 Building directory '/project/Users/'.
 Pre-compilation Complete
 ------ Publish started: Project: F:\...\project\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
 Connecting to site E:\project...
 Publishing directory /...
 ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
 ========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Are you sure you are publishing to correct location? What publish method are you using - Web Deploy, FTP, File System?

Comment: Are you using `-whatif`? Because that's a dry run. *The -whatif flag turns any Web Deploy command into a "dry run,"*

Comment: @dotnetom I am deploying in local directory and using "File System"

Comment: @ta.speot.is I am simply publishing dotnet code and using "File System".

Comment: @dotnetom I am deploying in http://127.0.0.1/(Folder) and using File System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

Publish in debug mode first then change settings and publish in release mode. it will surely work :)